# Why flink operator state is used together with heap object in official doc examples

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading doc on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#operator-state.

In the example class `BufferingSink`, `checkpointedState` is used together with `bufferedElements`.
Why not just use `checkpointedState` for buffering new object and cleared in `invoke` function?

Is this just an illustruation or performance related practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that choice was made in this case for performance reasons. Making an occasional copy (during checkpointing) is going to be less expensive than going through the overhead of going through the `ListState` object for every operation on the list.

Comment: `checkpointedState` is an Operator State, so the data is always on heap. All operations on `bufferedElements` are add, iterate element and clear. So I think there will be no performance difference between using `checkpointedState` together with `bufferedElements` and using `checkpointedState` alone.

Comment: ArrayList#size is O(1) -- it's just a variable lookup. ListState doesn't have an efficient size operation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use state as storage, checkpointedState will only be written to statebackend during the snapshot phase

Maybe you can first refer to the link below to understand the basic process of checkpoint https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/concepts/stateful-stream-processing/

Comment: Can you explain why it is better in this example to have both `List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> bufferedElements` and `ListState<Tuple2<String, Integer>> checkpointedState`? Why not just use the ListState for everything, instead of copying the buffered elements into it for checkpointing?

Comment: Yeah, this is a good question, I can briefly talk about my understanding, and welcome any suggestions. 


In this example, checkpointedState is state, which is mainly used for fault-tolerant design for job recovery, not for caching and calculation. 

BufferedElements is used for caching, and output after reaching a certain size.

Therefore, every time the program does Checkpoint, need to save BufferedElements to checkpointedState for task recovery